# How to make a function that adds a view to a view that has a UIBezierPath on it?

Tags: ios, swift, function, uibezierpath

viewforarow( )Must make a view that has the triangle on it ,that I mad with addArrowToView( ) ,but it shows just the view,without the triangle on it,in viewforarow( ) i used the addArrowToView( ) ,but doesn’t work. How can I fix that? What's the problem here?

```
func addArrowToView(_ view: UIView) {
     let arrowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
     let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
     let width = view.bounds.width
     let height = view.bounds.height
     
     trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: width - 2, y: height/2))
     trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 5, y: height ))
     trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 5, y: 0))
     
     trianglePath.close()
     
     arrowLayer.path = trianglePath.cgPath
     arrowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor // Replace with desired color
     arrowLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
     
     view.layer.addSublayer(arrowLayer)
}
    
func viewforarow(_ view: UIView) {
     let arrowContainerView = UIView()
    
     arrowContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
     arrowContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     
     view.addSubview(arrowContainerView)

      addArrowToView(arrowContainerView)

     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
     arrowContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
     arrowContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
     arrowContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.width / 3),
     arrowContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
     ])
}
```

Comment: I can't make sense of your description. Is the code you posted the problem code? How are you using that code in your app? Are you saying you can call addArrowToView() and it adds an arrow to a view, but you can't call `viewForArrow()`?

Comment: viewforarow( )Must make a view that has the triangle on it ,that I mad with addArrowToView( ) ,but it shows just the view,without the triangle on it,in viewforarow( ) i used the addArrowToView( ) ,but doesn’t work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not seeing triangle because your are building the bezier path based on the view's current width and height... but the approach you are taking does so when the view has a size of **Zero**.

Take a look at another approach...

We'll create a `UIView` subclass called `ArrowHeadView`:

```
class ArrowHeadView: UIView {

    // use the "base" layer as a shape layer
    lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = self.layer as! CAShapeLayer
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // Create the path.
        let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
        
        trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY))
        trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
        trianglePath.close()
        
        shapeLayer.path = trianglePath.cgPath
    }

}
```

That view will keeps the triangle shape sized to itself.

A quick view controller example...

We will add:

- an arrow view at 100x100 points, with red arrow and lightGray background
- an arrow view at 50x150 points, with blue arrow and yellow background
- a "container" view (very light gray background), with an arrow view as a subview constrained to the trailing end ... and we'll make the arrow green with a clear background

It will look like this:

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let arrowViewA = ArrowHeadView()
        let arrowViewB = ArrowHeadView()
        let arrowViewC = ArrowHeadView()

        let containerView = UIView()
        
        [arrowViewA, arrowViewB, arrowViewC, containerView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        containerView.addSubview(arrowViewC)
            
        [arrowViewA, arrowViewB, containerView].forEach { v in
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            arrowViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            arrowViewA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            arrowViewA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            arrowViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
            arrowViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: arrowViewA.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            arrowViewB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            arrowViewB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            arrowViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: arrowViewB.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            
            arrowViewC.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            arrowViewC.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            arrowViewC.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            arrowViewC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: arrowViewC.heightAnchor),

        ])
        
        arrowViewA.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.systemRed.cgColor
        arrowViewB.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        arrowViewC.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor

        arrowViewA.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        arrowViewB.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }

}
```

Comment: yes sir. Don Mag in the building , thank you so much